# Método remove() não remove objeto do ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Estou com uma duvida para remover um objeto de uma lista em um trabalho. Tenho uma classe automovel:

```
public class Automovel {
     String marca;
     String modelo;
     String preco;



    Automovel(String marca, String modelo, String preco) {
       this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.preco = preco;
    }
// ja esta como geter e seters
```

Também tenho uma classe concessionaria que implementa essa classe:

```
package metodista.ads.carro;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author Luiz Ricardo
 */
public class Concessionaria {

    public Concessionaria() {
    }

    ArrayList<Automovel> carros = new ArrayList<>();

    //O método adicionaVeiculo deverá adicionar um veículo ao estoque (atributo listaAutomoveis).
    public void adicionaVeiculo(Automovel automovel){
         carros.add(automovel);
    }
    // O método vendaVeiculo remove um veículo do estoque.
    public void vendaVeiculo(Automovel automovel){
        carros.remove(automovel);
    }

    //O método consultaEstoqueVeiculo devolve os veículos em estoque.
    public String consultaEstoqueVeiculo(){
        return carros.size()+"";
    }


}
//
```

minha classe main, tem uma tela para entrada de dados do usuario, minha duvida é no metodo para remover um objeto Automovel, tenho um botão que ao ser clicado precisaria tirar um objeto automovel do estoque, mas não funciona:

```
private void btVenderActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {     
 // construtor concessionaria        
Concessionaria con = new Concessionaria(); 

        String marca = tfMarca.getText();
        String modelo = tfModelo.getText();
        String preco = tfPreco.getText();
        Automovel auto2 = new Automovel(marca, modelo, preco);
        con.vendaVeiculo(auto2);
```

minha classe main, tem uma tela para entrada de dados do usuario, minha duvida é no **metodo vendaDeVeiculo** para remover um objeto Automovel.

Comment: Primeiro voce precisa definir uma forma e identificar cada carro(como um id por exemplo), sem isso é impossivel fazer o que ta querendo.

Comment: Outra coisa, seu código tem um erro de lógica: se você quer remover um carro ja existente, porque cria uma nova concessionaria e um novo carro ao remover? Isso nao faz sentido algum pro que ta querendo fazer, por isso é importante fornecer um **[mcve]** pois o erro não está nesse codigo apenas

Comment: Posso definir uma forma de iniciar o contador indicando q e spoiler a quantidade máxima de carros no estoque, depois ir adicionando e removendo, passado p o índice da lista ?

Answer (score 1):

Não funciona porque o `Automovel` que o método tenta remover não existe no ArrayList.

O método `remove()` usa a implementação padrão do método `equals()`, do objecto a remover, para verificar se ele existe no ArrayList.
A implementação padrão apenas verifica se é a mesma instância.

Se usar assim funciona:

```
ArrayList<Automovel> carros = new ArrayList<>();

Automovel auto1 = new Automovel("marca1", "modelo1", preco);
carros.add(auto1);
Automovel auto2 = new Automovel("marca2", "modelo1", preco);
carros.add(auto2);

carros.remove(auto1);
```

Como o método `remove()` depende do método `equals()` para poder identificar quando dois objectos são iguais(representam a mesma entidade), este terá de ser sobrescrito de acordo com os requisitos de igualdade.

Tem de determinar quais o campos da classe `Automovel` identificam um `Automovel`, quais o tornam único e usá-los na implementação do método equals().

Por exemplo, se considerar que dois carros são o mesmo se forem da mesma marca e modelo, uma implementação possível para o método equals() é:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    // verifica se é o mesmo objecto
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    // verifica se é null
    if (o == null)
        return false;
    // verifica tipo e cast
    if (getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;

    Automovel automovel = (Automovel) o;
    // Comparação atributo a atributo
    // Note que cada um dos atributos têm também de implementar correctamente o método equals()
    return  Objects.equals(marca, automovel.marca) &&
            Objects.equals(modelo, automovel.modelo);
}
```

Comment: Acho que apenas isso nao resolveria o problema. Se voce notar, ele cria uma nova concessionaria cada vez que executa o listener do botao, ou seja, nao vai remover nada pois concessionaria é criada sempre com uma lista vazia.

Comment: Poderia então criar um vetor, informando que seria um estoque total de carros e ir adicionando e removendo nas posições?

Comment: @Articuno Sim isso também é problema. No entanto, a questão principal e porventura a mais útil para o AP e outros é a da sobrescrita do método `equals()`.

Comment: @ramaral sim mas por parecer se tratar de uma aplicaçao swing e por ser um usuario iniciante, é importante ressaltar isso tambem, pois em nada adiantará ele sobrescrever o método equals sem consertar o problema que eu citei, vai continuar dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: @Articuno você já tinha dado essa informação no seu comentário na pergunta. Esse problema é especifico do AP enquanto a falta da sobrescrita é mais comum de se verificar. É mais provável que esta pergunta/resposta seja procurada pela segunda razão. Por essas razões preferi apenas focar a sobrescrita.

Comment: Ricardo, isso dependo do que pretende fazer. O "normal" é esse tipo de objectos terem identidade, determinada por um ou mais campos da classe.